# Generate a running-sum or row-sum in Elixir

Tags: elixir, list-comprehension

Given:

```
 data = [[1,2,3, ..., n],[1,2,3, ..., n],[1,2,3, ..., n], ...] 
# List with N rows of equal length
```

How may we get a row sum: `[3,6,9, ..., x]`

It is not immediately obvious which of the `Enum` functions to use, or how to *hold a running sum* using list comprehension

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say, the most readable way would be:

```
data
|> Enum.zip()
|> Enum.map(fn {v1, v2} -> v1 + v2 end)    
#⇒ [2, 4, 6, ..., x]
```

---

For the case of `N` lists, there is a recursion to be used:

```
data = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]

defmodule ListSum do
  def mapper([inner1 | [inner2 | rest]]) do
    reduced = inner1
              |> Enum.zip(inner2)
              |> Enum.map(fn {v1, v2} -> v1 + v2 end)
    mapper([reduced | rest])
  end
  def mapper([list]) when is_list(list), do: list
end

IO.inspect ListSum.mapper(data)
#⇒ [3, 6, 9]
```

The thing is in Erlang/Elixir the easiest approach to extend the solution to a list of inputs is to recursively simplify anything down to a case of a single argument. There are [probably] many ways to rewrite the example above to be better optimized, but I explicitly wrote it the most evident way.

---

The more evident (yet idiomatically wrong) way for those coming from OO background would be to `zip` and `map` tuples to lists:

```
data
|> Enum.zip()
|> Enum.map(fn e -> e |> Tuple.to_list() |> Enum.reduce(&Kernel.+/2) end)
```

---

#### Benchmarks:

```
defmodule ListSum do
  def mapper([inner1 | [inner2 | rest]]) do
    reduced = inner1
              |> Enum.zip(inner2)
              |> Enum.map(fn {v1, v2} -> v1 + v2 end)
    mapper([reduced | rest])
  end
  def mapper([list]) when is_list(list), do: list

  def ttler(data) do
    data
    |> Enum.zip()
    |> Enum.map(fn e -> e |> Tuple.to_list() |> Enum.sum() end)
  end
end

defmodule ListSumBench do
  use Benchfella

  @list Enum.to_list(1..1_000)
  @lists List.duplicate(@list, 1_000)

  bench "mapper" do
    ListSum.mapper @lists
  end

  bench "ttler" do
    ListSum.ttler @lists
  end
end
```

Results:

```
Compiling 2 files (.ex)
Generated ttl app
Settings:
  duration:      1.0 s

## ListSumBench
[16:49:06] 1/2: mapper
[16:49:09] 2/2: ttler

Finished in 5.56 seconds

## ListSumBench
benchma iterations   average time 
mapper          50   50194.78 µs/op
ttler           10   223662.80 µs/op
```

The difference between `Enum.sum` and `Enum.reduce(&Kernel.+/2)` is insignificant, but `sum` is a bit faster (like 3%.)

Comment: here's the problem: copying and reusing your code is easy... but understanding **why** it works, or why this is the obvious way to do it is not so clear

Comment: I was trying to write a descriptive “why” but I am a bit out of ideas, what could be a proper wording here. We have two lists of the same length, hence `Enum.zip/2` came to my mind. Now we have a single list of tuples, hence `Enum.map/2`. Probably if you’d state _what_ is a show-stopper in the understanding why is it that way, I could do better in expressing _why_.

Comment: I believe `Enum.reduce(&Enum.zip/2)` can be simplified to `Enum.zip()`

Comment: @mudasobwa would this extend to the case of N lists of equal length?

Comment: Nope, but I will update the answer for the case of N lists.

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: @mudasobwa thanks, the expanded answer for N rows is clear now, but wouldn't it be simple to terminate on an empty list instead of testing is_list() for each iteration?

Comment: Welcome. I am not sure I follow. Each iteration, save for the very last one, will be pattern matched directly to the first clause. `is_list` guard is there in the second clause just for the sake of clarity, it could be easily omitted if you are positive the input data is fine. It basically enforces `[1]` input to fail fast rather than to produce an erroneous `1` result.

Comment: Why not just do this for N lists: `|> Enum.zip |> Enum.map(fn t -> t |> Tuple.to_list |> Enum.sum end)`?

Comment: @Dogbert I am not sure how it differs from my last snippet; anyway I would expect `Tuple.to_list/1` to be way slower on huge `N`. I will do a benchmark when I’ll reach the computer.

Comment: @Dogbert according to the benchmark, the recursion is reproducibly 4.5× faster than `Tuple.to_list/1`.

Comment: Oops I didn't notice your last snippet which was the same as my comment. Re benchmark, I'm guessing the slow part here is `Enum.zip/1` because it has to construct 1000 tuples of size 1000 each while the other solution actually sums the contents of the lists. The difference should be smaller if your recursive solution constructs a list of lists first and then sums it. Anyways, your recursive solution is great for OP!